# Any delegate method after collection view is ready?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview

I want to call didSelectItemAtIndexPath: for particular index path but I can't call it programmatically in cellForItemAtIndexPath because collection is not yet ready, I will get cell as nil. Do we have any delegate method or any other UIView method that is called after collection view is ready?

I have tried willDisplayCell: but it is not made for relevant work, couldn't find anything else.

Comment: you need not to call delegate methods. Those are called at run time. kIndly let us know what are r u trying to achieve so that we can help you in the same.

Comment: Yes, actually I have a calendar collection view user selects a date and didSelect is called but when he leaves and come back I'm persisting index path and and calling didSelect to highlight the date which he selected previously.
     
So if I don't call this at runtime when user get back to this screen then I have to do manual logics and if else conditions to give border and logically calling didSelect in this case make sense.

Concept is like when user get back to that screen, it is called as user has selected an item.

Comment: I had added ans to your question. Do let me know if it worked for you .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to call `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`

Don't. This is a delegate method. It is called by the runtime when the user selects an item. You must *never* call this yourself.

Comment: Yes, actually I have a calendar collection view user selects a date and didSelect is called but when he leaves and come back I'm persisting index path and and calling didSelect to highlight the date which he selected previously.

Comment: So if I don't call this at runtime when user get back to this screen then I have to do manual logics and if else conditions to give border and logically calling didSelect in this case make sense

Comment: Concept is like when user get back to that screen, it is called as user has selected an item.

Comment: `UICollectionView` has a `selectItemAtIndexPath:` method for doing that, don't manually call delegate methods.

Comment: @ArunKumar I believe I've answered the question you asked. You didn't ask the right way to do something; you just showed something you were doing and complained, and I explained that what you were doing was wrong.

Comment: @matt Thanks matt. I consider your answer. Thanks for clearing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it programmatically utilising your manual logics. :) 
The underlying concept is that get the indexes of selected cells and reload those specific cells only.
Declare a global var

```
NSMutableArray array_indexpath;
```

in your did select method add indexes of selected cells.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    array_indexpath=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [array_indexpath addObject:indexPath];
   [self.myCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:array_indexpath];
}
```

and in your cell for cellForItemAtIndexPath method check the indexes and reload it as required.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ShubhCalendarCollectionViewCell *cell =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ShubhCalendarCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    if (array_indexpath.count !=0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<[array_indexpath count]; i++)
        {
            if ([array_indexpath objectAtIndex:i] == indexPath)
            {
                cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
            }
        }
    }
return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps..  Happy Coding.. :)